# how to show calendar on text box click in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In html i want to show **calendar** to select date while **clicking a text box.**
then we select a date from that calendar then the **selected** date will be display in **that** text box.

Comment: Have you tried any js calendars? Simple google search should provide some options.

Comment: checkout updated answer

Answer (score 22):

Starting with HTML5, `<input type="date" />` will do just fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8N6KH/

Comment: If you look more closely at that page, Opera used to have full support but got rid of it, and no browser fully supports it at the moment. Chrome and Firefox have partially supported it for over a year and it seems no progress has been made.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I guess that my answer will be good enough in a year or two. Chrome for Android has full support, so they will probably fully support it for desktops soon enough.

Comment: Downvoter, care to state your opinion? We can all learn from each other.

Comment: 1 year has passed: Opera and Chrome have full support, Edge supports it partially, FF and Safari don't like the progress.

Comment: I'm so over the jQuery plugin. Its 2016, I'm trying to not use jQuery on my websites! I wish more people were on board.

Answer (score 6):

You should read-up on [jQueryUI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Once you include the relevant jQuery UI library, it's as simple as,

**Script:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Pros:

- it is thoroughly tested for x-browser compatibility, so you won't have a problem.
- Separate css file, so you can customize it as per your liking

Comment: I tried this code but how can i change the color of the date numbers in that because many numbers are not visible due to the background color of my page

Answer (score 3):

try to use jquery-ui

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>   
    $(function() {
         $( "#calendar" ).datepicker();   
    }); 
</script>

<p>Calendar: <input type="text" id="calendar" /></p>
```

[more](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Check out the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and the source code.

Comment: i want to do it in jQuery mobile site

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use any javascript html calendar widget.

try this [calendar view widget](http://calendarview.org/), just copy-paste some code shown in example there and thats it what you want.

Here is the link to Jquery Mobile date box - [JQM datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/)

Answer (score 1):

yeah you will come across of various issues using HTML5 datepicker, it would work with some or might not be. I faced the same issue. Please check this [DatePicker Demo](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/), I solved my problem with this plugin. Its very good and flexible datepicker plugin with complete demo. It is completely compatible with mobile browsers too and can be integrated with jquery mobile too.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Date Picker You can refer [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/GUI-Components/HTMLDatePicker.htm).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile has a datepicker too. [Source](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/)

Just include the following files,

```
  <script src="jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
```