# How to get the calendar select in HTML?

Tags: html, calendar

I am looking for a standard calendar to select a date (and every time actualized by the day of today). In HTML, I know that there is something like this, when clicking on the small calendar icon. but I don't find it. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show calendar on text box click in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061011/how-to-show-calendar-on-text-box-click-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the "date" input type, simply use something like:

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="dateinput" >
```

as part of a form.